# Python GUI popup

Tags: python, user-interface

```
  import random
  import string
  import PySimpleGUI as sg
  filename = r'C:\Users\teeki\Documents\Passwords\passwords.txt'
  
  def new_password():
      print("For which account you want your password: ")
  
      account = input();
  
      length = int(input('\nHow long do you want your password to be: '))
  
      lower = string.ascii_lowercase
      upper = string.ascii_uppercase
      num = string.digits
      symbols = string.punctuation
      #All possible symbols to be used in password
      all_symbols = lower + upper + num + symbols
      #we generate <length> long password and print it out
      temp = random.sample(all_symbols,length)
      password = "".join(temp)
  
  
      # We save password to the passwords.txt
      text_file = open(r'C:\Users\teeki\Documents\Passwords\passwords.txt' , 'a')
      n = text_file.write('\n' + account + ' password: ' + password)
      text_file.close()
  
      print("Your password is: ", password)
  
  
  def popup_text(filename, text):
  
      layout = [
          [sg.Multiline(text, size=(80, 25)),],
      ]
      win = sg.Window(filename, layout, modal=True, finalize=True)
  
      while True:
          event, values = win.read()
          if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
              break
      win.close()
  
  sg.theme('LightBlue3')
  layout = [[sg.Text("Welcome to Password Generator")], [sg.Button("Exit")], [sg.Button("Password List"), sg.Button("New Password")]]
  window = sg.Window("Password Generator", layout)
  
  
  while True:
      event, values = window.read()
      
      if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
          break
      elif event == "Password List":
          with open(filename, "rt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
              text = f.read()
              popup_text(filename, text)
      elif event == "New Password":
          new_password()       
  window.close()
```

I need help with making a popup. So far the code works just fine, but instead of when i press on `New Password` printing on terminal i want it to open new popup where i would have 2 input fields and button to save password into .txt file.

I've tried messing around with `sg.Popup` but i cant get it to work properly. So any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: if you get error message then show it in question - always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: as I know `popup` in most GUIs is used only to display message. You should use `pg.Window` to create it.

Comment: It doesnt show error. Code "works" but not how i want it to work

Comment: then you should show this code with `Popup` and describe what is wrong with this `Popup` and then we can see if we can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Example for you,

```py
import random
import string
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def generate_password(account, length):
    return 'new password'

filename = r'C:\Users\teeki\Documents\Passwords\passwords.txt'

def new_password():

    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Password Account"), sg.Input(key='account')],
        [sg.Text("Password Length "), sg.Input(key='length' )],
        [sg.Button("Generate"), sg.Text("", size=(0, 1), key='password')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('New Password', layout, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "Generate":
            account = values['account']
            length = int(values['length'])
            password = generate_password(account, length)
            if password:
                window['password'].update(value=password)
            else:
                window['password'].update(value='')
    window.close()

def popup_text(filename, text):
    sg.Window(filename, [[sg.Multiline(text, size=(80, 25))]], modal=True
        ).read(close=True)

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Welcome to Password Generator")],
    [sg.Button("Exit")],
    [sg.Button("Password List"), sg.Button("New Password")]]
window = sg.Window("Password Generator", layout)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Password List":
        with open(filename, "rt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            text = f.read()
            popup_text(filename, text)
    elif event == "New Password":
        new_password()
window.close()
```